# Getting error while installing Firestore in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add `pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'` and updating cocoapods, but it's getting error.[image: click_here] And it saying **Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Firestore` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target**, for this I have tried all possible ways like pod repo update -> pod install -> pod update. Still I am facing same issue.

Comment: What version of CocoaPods, what version of Xcode and what iOS version is your apps deployment targeting?

Comment: @AdamRichardson : Xcode-9.3, CocoaPods-1.5.0 and iOS-10.2

Comment: Check your swift version. Build setting -> search swift language.

Comment: @Puvanarajan Swift : 3.3

Comment: @KarthikMandava then you pod file mention the version. Eg pod 'Firebase/Core' ~ x.x

Comment: @Puvanarajan May I know which version I need to use ?

Comment: @KarthikMandava need to search. or your pod file check the the minimum version. platform :ios, '10.0'

Answer (score 0):

This is https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1845 that was fixed two weeks ago. Make sure that you update to Firebase 5.8.1 or higher.

If the update isn't happening for some reason, look for clues as to why in the `Podfile.lock` file.